# Scope using AdvancedSearch method for entire mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook, advanced-search

I am trying to look through all Outlook folders for mail items matching certain parameters to save the attachment, from Excel.

I don't know how to reference scope to go through all folders, even custom folders.

I can't find the resources that answer my question.

```
Sub testing()

Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim scope As String
Dim filter As String
Dim rsts As Results
Dim AdvancedSearch As Outlook.Search

blnSearchComp = False

'I want it to search the entire mail account including normal folders like inbox and sent as well as custom folders.
'but this doesn't work. Any ideas?
scope = "'Fakeexample123@outlook.com'"
'filter assignment statement has been excluded

Set AdvancedSearch = myOlApp.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, True, "test")  

While blnSearchComp <> True
    If AdvancedSearch.Results.Count > 0 Then
        blnSearchComp = True
    End If
Wend

Set rsts = AdvancedSearch.Results

For x = rsts.Count To 1 Step -1
    rsts.Attachment.Item(x).SaveAsFile Project
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you [edit] this question only address a single issue?  It is difficult in this format to address multiple questions at once... it becomes a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I know it isn't the best solution, but I have come up with the following code to make a list of all of the parent folders, so that a for loop can be used with advanced search method to iterate the list. This will not be the fastest possible code, but should not be too slow.

```
Sub main()
'establishes connections
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set objNS = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'pick highest folder level as original my folder
Set myFolder = objNS.Folders("faxe.example123@outlook.com")

Call ProcessFolders(myFolder)

End Sub

Sub ProcessFolders(myFolder)

're establish connections
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set objNS = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'set up collection
Set x = New Collection

For Each objFolder In myFolder.Folders
'add all parent folder names to collection
'advanced search method will handle subfolders
'can use a recursive call here also to get subfolders though
    x.Add objFolder.Name
Next


Set objNS = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set myOlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Scope should be

```
'\\Fakeexample123@outlook.com'
```

```vb
Sub Demo_scopeformat()

Dim myOlApp As New outlook.Application
Dim scope As String

' Mailbox
scope = "'" & myOlApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.folderPath & "'"

' Expected format
Debug.Print scope

End Sub
```