# Access Group Inbox Instead of Personal - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Apologies in advance, I understand that this has been answered previously under

[Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox?newreg=2200800e83f24f46b89e33ac96202462)

However, I am unable to get the solutions there to work. Essentially, this code gets run through, but does not generate any output. I would expect the end result to be a saved email to my drafts. The code is written in Excel and accesses Outlook.

I am using the below code to search a specific string from Excel in Outlook, find the most recent email, and draft a response to it. The .count debug is not printing due to an "object variable or with block not set" error. This is not breaking the code, but is not defining. The olitem.display is not displaying the email being replied to either, so I'm assuming the issue is that it's unable to locate the correct shared inbox.

As a note, I have tried this same code for a different process using my personal inbox and it worked without issue. I'm not very familiar with Outlook, so any resources along with an explanation for what is causing this would be great!

```vb
    Dim reference as String 
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim IsOutlookCreated As Boolean
    Dim sFilter As String
    Dim olitem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olReply As MailItem
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    On Error Resume Next 
    Set OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        IsOutlookCreated = True
    End If

    Set ns = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myfolder = ns.Folders("Name of Inbox")
    Set myfolder = myfolder.Folders("Inbox") 
                     
    sFilter = "[Subject] = '" & reference & "'"
    With myfolder.Items.Restrict(sFilter)
     If .Count > 0 Then
       Debug.Print .Count
       .Sort "ReceivedTime", True
       Set olitem = .item(1)
       olitem.Display
       Set olReply = olitem.ReplyAll
          If olitem.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then 
             olreply.save
           End if
    end if
    end with
```

Is it possible that this is a security or access issue?

Comment: You need to comment out that `On Error Resume Next` or at least cancel it with `On Error Goto 0` once you've set `OutlookApp`

Comment: Although adding `On Error GoTo 0` just before `Set ns =` is mandatory it is still too dangerous. Take a look at the code in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891245/getobject-outlook-application-not-working-with-outlook-open where the error bypass is removed after only one line.

Comment: I added the On Error Goto 0 line, but still facing the same issue. It's skipping over the "If .Count > 0" line, I don't think it's able to probably set the Inbox. It looks like myfolder = "Inbox", is that correct?

Comment: Insert `myfolder.Display` under `Set myfolder = myfolder.Folders("Inbox")` to confirm the folder.

Comment: Hi Niton, good point there, didn't think to check that. It is able to display the correct folder. There are no items within Inbox, but when you manually search for an item it's able to find them. Should I not be setting it to a folder, but the entire group box for the search instead? Basically, items come into the general Inbox and get sorted into different sub folders. Usually the inbox is closed, but I'm able to search string "xyz" in the inbox to find what I'm looking for (even though there are no visible items).

Comment: Correction: Usually the inbox is empty* (couldn't edit after 5 minutes, apologies.)

Comment: Not my post so prepend @ to the username to respond to comments.

Comment: Likely you could apply Restrict to a list of folder names.

Comment: Advanced Search can be applied to subfolders. Sample posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352259/scope-using-advancedsearch-method-for-entire-mailbox and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72871689/advancedsearch-method-not-searching-subfolders.